# form in wordpress adding row in spreadsheet

Tags: wordpress, google-sheets

I want to create a form in wordpress

that will add a row into a google spreadsheet

what is the best way to do that?

any example?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally create a Google Form that has fields for the data you intend to have in your form in WordPress. Check the source of the Google generated form and duplicate the form (with your own styling) on your own site, as long as all of the field's names and id's match, the method is correct, and the action on the form tag is correct you should be able to submit the form and it will add a row to a spreadsheet.